# Prove ${a+b+c\over abc}\leq {1\over a^2}+{1\over b^2}+{1\over c^2}$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that 
$$\frac{a+b+c}{abc} \le \frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}+\frac1{c^2}$$
I started with this
$$\frac 1b\frac1c+\frac1a\frac1c+\frac1a\frac1b\le\frac1a\frac1a+\frac1b\frac1b+\frac1c\frac1c$$
then I stick here what can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Older question about the same problem: [Prove $\frac{a+b+c}{abc} \leq \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840148) It was found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Ba%2Bb%2Bc%5Cover%20abc%7D%5Cleq%20%7B1%5Cover%20a%5E2%7D%2B%7B1%5Cover%20b%5E2%7D%2B%7B1%5Cover%20c%5E2%7D%24&p=1). For more advice on searching see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)